# can't close message in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm new to Django and I tried to integrate message alerts in my code using a tutorial. These are showed fine but I can't close them using the 'x' button.

[image]

This is the code for the message section:

```
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert" >
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    {{ message }}
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That looks like Bootstrap. Have you included the Bootstrap JavaScript in your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Using this, messages automatically hide after 3 seconds and you can change it. Its better because no one just again and again close the message.

# Simple add id="message_box", here is the code:

{% for message in messages %}
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert" id="message_box">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    {{ message }}
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}



Write this in your base.html.

<script>
var message_tag = document.getElementById("message_box");

setTimeout(function(){ 
   message_tag.style.display = "none"; 
}, 3000);    # 3000 is 3 seconds

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in place of the close button

```
<button type="button" 
        onclick="window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();">close</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution best solution of your problem. I have created a JavaScript function that hides the message whenever close button is clicked. It worked for me perfectly fine. It does not have any timer (delay), user can close it whenever he wants, it actually serves the purpose of a close button.
Try this it will work fine.

```
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert" id="message_box">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true" onclick="buttonclose()">&times;</span>
    </button>
    {{ message }}
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}


<script>
var message_tag = document.getElementById("message_box");
function buttonclose(){ 
   message_tag.style.display = "none"; 
};  

</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].